# Join year, month and day strings to form a date in format YYYY-MM-DD with moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In my application a user enters a year, a month and a day separately. I'm simply trying to display what they entered back to them for confirmation but I'd like to use moment instead of concatenating strings.

```
var year = "2023";
var month = "10";
var day = "20";
var date = new moment(
                year + month + day, "YYYY-MM-DD"
            );
console.log(date);
```

Strangely instead of returning "2023-10-20", it returns "1643950800000" and I'm not sure why. I'm not very familiar with momentJS.

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever considered reading [the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) as an option?

Comment: the manual explains this here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: That code doesn't output `1643950800000`?

Comment: you can use format `moment(year + month + day, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY-MM-DD")`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a moment by specifying some of the units in an [`object`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/).

**Demo:**

```js
var year = "2023";
var month = "10";
var day = "20";

var date = moment({
  year: year,
  month: month - 1, //months are zero-indexed
  day: day
});
console.log(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the docs (yes I should have gone there first, apologies).
This works:

```
var date = new moment(
 year + month + day, "YYYYMMDD"
).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```